# Are there any requests that cannot be redirected with Go+echo?

Tags: http, go, redirect, backend, echo

I am using Go (1.11) and echo in the web application I am developing, and redirect processing is performed with the following command.

`echoContext.Redirect(http.StatusFound,targetUrl)`

However, some requests can be successfully redirected, while others are not redirected.
The request is probably a GET request from the server, is there any request that cannot be redirected?

Comment: All ```targetUrls``` are the same URL.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Go1.11 @Flimzy

Comment: Go 1.11 is also very old (released in 2019), and unlikely supported by modern versions of Echo. Can you use 1.18 or 1.19?

Comment: I can't it. But, 
I suspect that there is something more to do with the HTTP communication rather than the Go version issue.
First of all, I want to know the cause.

Comment: What does it mean that some requests are not redirected? What behavior do you observe?

Comment: Normally the redirect process runs with the above code, but that process does not run for some reason.
Even if I check the log, the request after the redirect did not come.
However, only some requests cannot be redirected.

Comment: Please add some debugging output, to elaborate on what you're seeing. "the process does not run" is not a very useful error description.

Comment: It's probably caused by server-side cURL configuration.
Thank you @Flimzy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there seems to be a setting in the cURL option that does not follow the redirect of the request destination.
This was probably the cause.